# How to group by only 2 rows of a column?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq, entity-framework

I Have a Table like this:

```
Column1      Column2
 type1          2
 type1          5
 type2          3
 type3          4
 type4          2
```

I need to to group by only `type1` and `type2` and show them as `typeX`. something like this:

```
Column1      Column2
 typeX          10
 type3          4
 type4          2
```

I have no idea how to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select (case when Column1 in ('type1','type2') then 'typeX' else Column1 end) as Column1,
    sum(Column2) as Column2 
from Table_Name 
group by (case when Column1 in ('type1','type2') then 'typeX' else Column1 end)
```

Comment: Have you tested your code? I get error "Invalid column name 'typeX'."

Comment: +1 Beat me to it. My fiddle works, add single quotes to 'typeX' in `Group BY`.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:** The query that will work in this case is shown below. I have used `Column1` as `Type` and `Column2` as `val`.

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN Type in ('type1','type2') THEN 'typeX' 
        ELSE Type 
    END [Type],
    SUM(val) [Val] 
FROM Tab 
GROUP BY (CASE WHEN Type IN ('type1','type2') THEN 'typeX' ELSE Type END)
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3db6f/4) with the answer.

Comment: You should add the sql here too, so that the answer stands on its own when the fiddle isn't reachable for some reason.

Comment: Thank you, It's what I want.